# Android Connect To WS Protocol

Tags: java, android, node.js, websocket

I created an Node JS (using WebSocket) server for my client. I tested it with Javascript and it all works fine. But now I want to use that connection in my app. The connection uses the WS protocol (ws://) and the server sends messages while the connection is open.

My question is: how should I open an ws:// connection and read the incoming messages?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a WebSocket client library for Android/Java. You might have a look at [AutobahnAndroid](http://autobahn.ws/android/).

Disclosure: I am original author of Autobahn and work for Tavendo.

Comment: Great! Feel free to ask for help here or on the Autobahn mailing list should you run into issues with WebSocket and/or AutobahnAndroid ..

Comment: @oberstet It Does not seems to be working it anymore. I have issue with my socket channel, I am not able to receive messages in some phones. Is there a better way to address this issue. I am using [this](https://github.com/sacOO7/socketcluster-client-java) library and posted the issue as well [issue](https://github.com/sacOO7/socketcluster-client-java/issues/43).

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Autobahn Android lib and its working fine with the WS protocol but when i changed into WSS it not working for me (TCP connection is not getting established) one more thing the certificate is not self signed